# Absolute Distinct Numbers

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm

I am writing an exercises on codility via c++. Here the question:

> A non-empty zero-indexed array A consisting of N numbers is given. The
>   array is sorted in non-decreasing order. The absolute distinct count
>   of this array is the number of distinct absolute values among the
>   elements of the array.
>
> For example, consider array A such that:
>
> ```
> A[0] = -5
> A[1] = -3
> A[2] = -1
> A[3] =  0
> A[4] =  3
> A[5] =  6
> ```
>
> The absolute distinct count of this array is 5, because there are 5 distinct absolute values among the elements of this array,
>   namely 0, 1, 3, 5 and 6.
>
> Write a function:
>
> `int solution(vector<int> &A);`
>
> that, given a non-empty zero-indexed array A consisting of N numbers,
>   returns absolute distinct count of array A.
>
> For example, given array A such that:
>
> ```
> A[0] = -5
> A[1] = -3
> A[2] = -1
> A[3] =  0
> A[4] =  3
> A[5] =  6
> ```
>
> the function should return 5, as explained above.
>
> Assume that:
>
> `N` is an integer within the range `[1..100,000]`; 
>   each element of array `A`
>   is an integer within the range `[−2,147,483,648..2,147,483,647]`; 
>   array
>   `A` is sorted in non-decreasing order.
>
> Complexity:
>
> expected worst-case time complexity is `O(N);`
>    expected worst-case space
>   complexity is `O(N)`, beyond input storage (not counting the storage
>   required for input arguments).
>
> Elements of input arrays can be
>   modified.

I am writing down the following code, and I fail to find any problems in my code, but it just doesn't pass.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>


int solution(vector<int> &A) {
    int N(A.size());
    vector<long long> B(N,0);
    int counter(1);
    //int index(0);
    int move1(0);
    int move2(N-1);
    if(N==1)
        {return 1;}
    if(N==0)
        {return 0;}
    if(N==2)
        {
            if(abs(A[0])==abs(A[1]))
                {return 1;}
            else{return 2;}
        }

    for (int i = 0 ; i < N ; ++i)
        {
            B[i]=abs((long long )A[i]);
        }


    while(move1<move2)
        {
            if(B[move1]==B[move1+1])
                {move1+=1;}

            else if(B[move2]==B[move2]-1)
                {move2-=1;}

            else if(B[move1]>B[move2])
                {
                    counter+=1;
                    move1+=1;
                }
            else if(B[move1]<B[move2])
                {
                    counter+=1;
                    move2-=1;
                }
            else{move1+=1;}
        }

    return counter;
}
```

Here's the link of performance, https://codility.com/demo/results/trainingUT9QAN-JMM/
There's some errors but I can't figure out its detail, if anyone could help me with my code, I will really appreciate!

Thanks!

Comment: You're getting downvoted for a few reasons. 1. You need to boil down the question into as small an explanation and example as possible, this has quite a lot of repetition and fluff that doesn't need to be there. 2. This really sounds like a homework problem (which people here don't like even though it is allowed to get help on homework). 3. You are basically asking us to debug your code for you, which is off topic without a specific code problem (whereas yours is a general "this doesn't work" problem)

Comment: @KevinWells Codility is a programming challenges site, not really homework.

Comment: If you're taking codility tests to try to get hired as a programmer, surely you should know how to use a debugger to troubleshoot your code.

Comment: @Barmar Even if it were homework that isn't specifically disallowed here, I was just giving a possible reason why it is being downvoted since I know many new users are frustrated when they get downvotes and no comments. For the record I didn't downvote, but I did flag it as off-topic

Comment: Yes, I can't explicitly explain the problem because I have no idea how codility works on it. The only thing I know is that it returns 12 while the result should be 11 for simple no-negative numbers.

Comment: @ReynS Are you saying that it works correctly when you run it on your computer, and only fails when you submit it to codility?

Comment: Cause for some simple cases it works quite fine. The problem is that here I have no idea what extreme cases it is using here, so I fail to debug it for those extreme cases.

Comment: @ReynS _"I have no idea how codility works on it."_ Why do you expect someone here knows how its working? You've hit a common misconception that SO could be able to solve your problem with obscure/unknown test cases from online code judge engines. For valid questions here, the test cases need to be made clear with a [MCVE], otherwise they aren't helpful for any future research.

Comment: Also, your link to codility is now broken, so we can't even see the information that that would give us about what went wrong

Comment: Your `while` loop assumes that equal elements will be next to each other. That's true for the original values, but not true after you convert each of them to their absolute values.

Comment: https://codility.com/demo/results/trainingUT9QAN-JMM/      sorry about the link problem, here's the new one, hope it works.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks for your message. But here, I don't think that the order will be different, i.e. if there's -4, -4 as original values, then after taking absolute values of each one, one the same indices, they become 4, 4, which is still equivalent and hope that I can exclude this case.

Comment: I didn't understand how you were using `move1` and `move2` before, now I see it.

Comment: The only thing that is clear is that, if I have consecutive positive numbers like 5,5, they will be counted twice. That means the if statement got sth wrong, but I fail to find it.

Comment: Now I get it solved, stupid mistakes, sorry about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to have an iterative solution.  Start from both ends and work your way inward toward 0.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>

size_t solution( const std::vector< int > & A )
{
    std::vector< int >::const_iterator f( A.begin() );
    std::vector< int >::const_reverse_iterator b( A.rbegin() );

    size_t result = 0;
    if( A.size() )
        for( ; ( f != A.end() ) && ( b != A.rend() ); )
        {
            if( *f >= 0 )
                return result + ( ( A.end() - f ) - ( b - A.rbegin() ) );
            else if( *b <= 0 )
                return result + ( ( A.rend() - b ) - ( f - A.begin() ) );
            else if( *f == -*b )
                ++result, ++f, ++b;
            else if( *f > -*b )
                ++result, ++b;
            else
                ++result, ++f;
        }
    return result;
}


int main( int, char ** )
{
    std::cout << solution( std::vector< int >{ -5, -3, -1, 0, 3, 6} ) << std::endl;
    std::cout << solution( std::vector< int >{ -5, -3, -1, 0, 1, 3, 6} ) << std::endl;
    std::cout << solution( std::vector< int >{ -5, -3, -1, 0, 2, 3, 6} ) << std::endl;
    std::cout << solution( std::vector< int >{ -5, -3, -1, 3, 6} ) << std::endl;
    std::cout << solution( std::vector< int >{ -5, -3, -1, 0, 3, 4, 5} ) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

100% solution with Ruby

```
def solution(a)
  a.each_with_object({}){ |el, acc| acc[el.abs] = true }.size
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Got 100/100 using Java 8 streams.

```
return (int) Arrays.stream(A).map(Math::abs)
            .distinct().count();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def solution(A):
 
    # Creates an empty hashset
    s = set()
    n = len(A)
     
    
    res = 0
    for i in range(n):
     
        # If not present, then put it in
        # hashtable and increment result
        if (A[i] not in s):
            s.add(A[i])
            res += 1
     
    return res
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Java an alternative solution by using custom iterator

import java.util.Iterator;

import static java.lang.String.format;

public final class AbsDistinct {
    private AbsDistinct() {
        super();
    }

    public static int nrOfAbsDistinctNumbers(
            final int[] sortedAscArray) {
        final Iterator<Long> iterator = new AbsDistinctIterator(sortedAscArray);
        int count = 0;
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            iterator.next();
            count++;
        }
        return count;
    }

    private static final class AbsDistinctIterator implements Iterator<Long> {
        private final int[] sortedArray;

        private int head;

        private int tail;

        AbsDistinctIterator(int[] sortedArray) {
            this.sortedArray = sortedArray;
            this.head = 0;
            this.tail = sortedArray.length - 1;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
            return head <= tail;
        }

        @Override
        public Long next() {
            final long headVal = Math.abs((long) sortedArray[head]);
            final long tailVal = sortedArray[tail];
            if (headVal > tailVal) {
                nextHeadVal();
                return headVal;
            }
            if (headVal == tailVal) {
                nextHeadVal();
                nextTailVal();
                return headVal;
            }
            nextTailVal();
            return tailVal;
        }

        private void nextHeadVal() {
            final int headVal = sortedArray[head];
            while (head <= tail && sortedArray[head] == headVal) {
                head++;
            }
            ;
        }

        private void nextTailVal() {
            final int tailVal = sortedArray[tail];
            while (tail >= head && sortedArray[tail] == tailVal) {
                tail--;
            }
            ;
        }
    }

    private static void assertCorrectNrOfAbsDistinctNumbers(final int[] array, final int expected) {
        final var calculated = nrOfAbsDistinctNumbers(array);
        if (calculated != expected) {
            throw new AssertionError(format("expected '%d' - calculated '%d'", expected, calculated));
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        assertCorrectNrOfAbsDistinctNumbers(new int[]{
                        -5, -3, -1, 0, 3, 6
                },5
        );
        assertCorrectNrOfAbsDistinctNumbers(new int[]{
                -2147483648, 5, 2147483647
        }, 3);
        assertCorrectNrOfAbsDistinctNumbers(new int[]{
                -2147483648, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 2147483647
        }, 3);
        assertCorrectNrOfAbsDistinctNumbers(new int[]{
                -2147483647
        }, 1);
        assertCorrectNrOfAbsDistinctNumbers(new int[]{
                -1, 0, 1, 2
        }, 3);
        assertCorrectNrOfAbsDistinctNumbers(new int[]{
                -1, 2
        }, 2);
        assertCorrectNrOfAbsDistinctNumbers(new int[]{
                -1, -2
        }, 2);
        assertCorrectNrOfAbsDistinctNumbers(new int[]{
                1, 2
        }, 2);
        assertCorrectNrOfAbsDistinctNumbers(new int[]{
                1
        }, 1);
        assertCorrectNrOfAbsDistinctNumbers(new int[]{
                -1
        }, 1);
        assertCorrectNrOfAbsDistinctNumbers(new int[]{
                -2, 1
        }, 2);
        assertCorrectNrOfAbsDistinctNumbers(new int[]{
                -5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 6, 7, 8, 9
        }, 9);
    }
}
```